# Three series of Kolmogorov

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables

Let $X_n\geqslant 0$ be a sequence of independent random variables. The following are equivalent:

$i) \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{ X_n} <\infty$ a.s

$ii)$ $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{ \mathbb P(X_n>1)} +\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{ \mathbb E X_n1_{X_n\le 1}} <\infty$

$iii)$ $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\mathbb E\left(\frac{X_n}{1+X_n}\right)} <\infty$

Maybe I have to use the Three series of Kolmogorov but I don't know how :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That (i) is equivalent to (ii) is exactly contained in the statement of Three series theorem of Kolmogorov up to the convergence of the series of variances. This can be tackled using $\mathbb E(X_n^2\chi_{\{X_n\lt 1\}})\leqslant \mathbb E(X_n\chi_{\{X_n\lt 1\}})$ and the square of the expectations is not problematic.

Assume (ii) holds. Then 
$$0\leqslant \mathbb E\left(\frac{X_n}{1+X_n}\right)\leqslant \mathbb P\{X_n\gt 1\}+\mathbb E[X_n\chi_{\{X_n\leqslant 1\}}].$$

Conversely, assume (iii) holds. Then 
$$\mathbb E[X_n\chi_{\{X_n\leqslant 1\}}]\leqslant 2\mathbb E\left(\frac{X_n}{1+X_n}\chi_{\{X_n\leqslant 1\}}\right)\leqslant 2\mathbb E\left(\frac{X_n}{1+X_n}\right),$$
and $\mathbb P\{X_n\gt 1\}=\mathbb P\left\{\frac{X_n}{1+X_n}\gt \frac 12\right\}$. An application of Markov's inequality shows the convergence of $\sum_n\mathbb P\{X_n\gt 1\}$.

Comment: This is the theorem. I only see that $i) \Rightarrow ii)$ but not conversely because we need the convergence of the variance series http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov's_three-series_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem

Comment: How did you deduce that inequalities so fast? Did you knew it?

Comment: @Shanks: we use non-negativeness of the $X_n$ in order to deduce convergence of the third series. The strategy in order to deduce the inequality is: I try to bound what I see in (ii) by terms of (iii) and conversely.

Comment: Sorry for ask, but I'm learning the tricks and I'm a little slow for this :/ But how can I prove the convergence using the non-negativeness of the $X_n$ and also I don't know how $P(X_n>1) = P(\frac{X_n}{X_n+1} > \frac{1}{2} )$ could be useful. I'm very confused :/

Comment: @Shanks See edit.

Comment: Excelent answer :)!