# Durrett Exercise 2.5.5 Convergence of Random Series

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory, measure-theory, self-learning

Let $X_n \geq 0$ be independent for $n \geq 1$. Then the following are equivalent:

(i) $\sum_{n=1}^\infty X_n$ converges a.s.

(ii)$\sum_{n=1}^\infty  {[P(X_n >1) + E[ X_n I_{X_n \leq 1} ] }]  < \infty $

(iii)$\sum_{n=1}^\infty E [ X_n / (1+ X_n)] < \infty $

How could we show the above?
I tried using Kolmogorov's Three-Series Theorem but I was unable to show it.

Comment: And also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/533404/